# Translating a form/input on the Z-axis

Tags: html, css, forms, input

When translating a form/input on the Z-axis, the area that accepts the cursor isn't brought forward in Z space with the apparent place of the element, and trying to click on the input box doesn't work unless you click where the element *would be* if it hadn't been translated. Is there any way to fix this?

HTML

```
<html>
<body>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/client-questionaire.css" type="text/css">

<div id="impress" data-transition-duration="3000">

    <div id="yourself" class="step page" data-x="0">
            <div class="innerDiv">
                <p class="mainWord">
                    <span class="textLength">
                        <span class="black">YOUR</span><span class="white">SELF</span>
                    </span>
                </p>
                <div class="wrap">
                    <div class="formBox">
                        <form id="yourselfForm" class="form">

                            <label for="firstName">
                                What's your <u>first name</u>?
                            </label><br>
                            <input name="firstName" type="text" ><br>

                            <label for="lastName">
                                What's your <u>last name</u>?
                            </label><br>
                            <input name="lastName" type="text" ><br>

                            <label for="currentJob">
                                What's your <u>current job title</u>?
                            </label><br>
                            <input name="currentJob" type="text" ><br>

                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div> 
    </div>
   <div id="intro" class="step page" data-x="2000">
        <div class="outerDiv">
            <div class="innerDiv">
                <p class="mainWord"><span class="black first">CREÆTIVE</span> <span class="white last">BRIEF</span></p>

                <div class="formBox">
                </div>
             </div>
        </div> 
    </div>
    <div id="lookFeel" class="step page" data-x="4000">
        <div class="outerDiv">
            <div class="innerDiv">
                <p class="mainWord"><span class="black firstSpan">LOOK</span> <span class="white secondSpan">&</span><span class="black"> FEEL</span></p>

                <div class="formBox">
                </div>
             </div>
        </div>   
    </div>
<script src="/js/impress.js"></script>
<script>
impress().init();
</script>
```

CSS

```
body {
    background: #cc9933;
}

.page {
    height: 830px;
    width: 1480px;
    margin: 0px;
}



.formBox {
    position:absolute;
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 450px;
    width: 270px;
    top: -150px;
    left: 867px;
    z-index: 21;
    background: #cc9933;
    transform: translateZ(300px);
}



.innerDiv {
    position:absolute;
    z-index: 9;
    width: 1000%;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    top:40%;
    height: 108px;
}

.frontFiller {
    transform: translateX(-2000px);
    width: 1000%;
}

.mainWord {
    margin: 0px 50px;
    font-size: 90px;
    height: 100%;
}

.black {
    color: black;
}

.white {
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: Any chance you could make a JSFiddle or CodePen example that reproduces the bug? Using the CSS you have provided I can't reproduce it.

Comment: I've tried to answer, but I'm not sure I got it right. Your example isn't too clear. Can you provide a [mcve]? That means leave everything out that isn't important to show what you want to achieve, but leave everything in that is actually necessary to reproduce the error...and read the article I linked, it's really helpful.

Comment: I notice that you edited your question to include more code. I still can't reproduce the bug, and I am hazy as to why you are using translateZ at all. What is its purpose in this layout?

Comment: I'm using impress.js for the animations from slide to slide, I'm having the div pop out so it slides across the page as it transition between slides

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're trying to achieve, your example moves the `input` outside of the viewport and the translation isn't working at all.

So, I'll take a guess: Have you tried setting the CSS property `perspective` on the parent of `.formBox`?

Here's an example that shows how it would work:

```css
.wrapper {
    perspective: 50px;
    transform-style:preserve-3d;
}
.formBox {
    position:absolute;
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 450px;
    width: 270px;
    left: 200px;
    z-index: 21;
    background: #cc9933;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(30px);   
    transform: translateZ(30px);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="formBox">
    <form id="yourselfForm" class="form">
        <label for="firstName">
        What's your <u>first name</u>?
        </label><br>
        <input name="firstName" type="text" >
    </form>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a browser bug, and specifically a Chrome bug. I can reproduce the effect from the HTML and CSS that you provided on Google Chrome. On Firefox (Quantum) it works as expected.

On Chrome, it only happens when you use both translateZ() AND z-index. If you can create your form without using z-index on the text fields, it should be fine.

Consider reporting this to [Google Chrome but tracker](http://dev.chromium.org/for-testers/bug-reporting-guidelines).